# Adding simple products quicker?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1

Hi I was wondering if there was a faster way of adding simple products to a configurable product instead of using the "Quick Create" option?

Basically I'm trying to add variation to a shoe with attributes Colour, Width and Size.

Now I have say 8 sizes of colour Black and width 4E. As you see, 2 of the attributes remain the same for 8 simple products and only the size changes.

It's a hassle to add each product one by one using the Quick Create option. Is there a better way of doing this? Like just selecting with sizes you want in a colour and width and then they are automatically added?

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not have exactly same feature as you want. But it provides facility to duplicate products.

To do so, open a product in admin panel and click on **`Duplicate`** button.

After doing this, Magento duplicates that product except few attributes. Below is the list:

- Status (blank)
- Inventory (0)
- Stock Status (out of stock)
- sku (blank)

If you use this feature, you can save much time in filling form each time you want to create a product.

Comment: Hi, I tried the duplicate option but it didn't copy the simple products which is what I require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV import option there you find attribute called additional attribute where u can attributes which are specific for product and  attribute configurable_variations which will take care mapping of sku.

Comment: Is that a template that I can use for teh csv file? Thanks.

Comment: yes u get template wish i would have attach here but could not find option to do that.

Comment: Can you guide me to where from to get the template?